# How to use method in Linq selectmany statement?

Tags: c#, linq

How to use method in linq selectmany statement?

```
public class BIT128Object
{
    public long High {get; set;}
    public long Low  {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

This class is used by express the integer indices from bit array. 
I want to extract all indices from BIT128Object.
(Exactly i want all cases of index and message pairs like a group by)
I define below method to parse bit high and bit low to int indices array.

```
private int[] ParseIndices(long high, long low)
{
    List<int> indexList = new List<int>();

    BitArray highBitArr = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(high));
    if(highBitArr != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        {
            if (highBitArr.Get(i) == true)
                indexList.Add(i + 64);
            }
        }


        BitArray lowBitArr = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(low));
        if(lowBitArr != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            {
                if (lowBitArr.Get(i) == true)
                     indexList.Add(i);
            }
         }


     return indexList.ToArray();
 }
```

And then, there is a BIT128Object list which has over 1000 count of elements.
I query by linq statement to get all each index's total count like this.

```
[Index]    [Count]    [Message]
   0          120       hello
   1          90        world
   1           3        hi
   2           3        hi
   2           2        hhhhiiii
   2           1        hiiiiii
 12231151      1        new
 12231151      1        new2222
105452984641   1        world
```

And below is my linq statement.

```
var datum = bitObjectList.SelectMany(x => ParseIndices(x.High, x.Low)
                             .Select(z => new { 
                               Index = z,
                               Message = x.Message
                             }));
```

But there is an exception occur while query linq.
The exception message is below.

> Cannot parse expression 'value(ClassName)' as it has an unsupported
>   type. Only query sources (that is, expressions that implement
>   IEnumerable) and query operators can be parsed.

I debugged as much as, i found that i can not pass x.High and x.Low parameters to ParseIndices(). Maybe it seems i must pass fixed value like ParseIndices(10,10000).
It looks like that i can't use method in selectmany statement in this case.

May i have some helps?

Comment: Is `var datum = BitObjectList = .SelectMany` only a copy & paste mistake or is this really your actual code?

Comment: The exception you provided cannot originate from the code in your question. There's something other you didn't show us. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I fixed my question code

Comment: Like dymanoid said this exception does not came from the code you've posted. Even when I try it I did not get any exception at all.

Comment: Exception stack trace would give better clue about the problem.

Comment: You don't say which LINQ provider you're using, but if it's EF Core, then [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7708) may be relevant

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ParseIndices(x.High, x.Low)`in LINQ query because the LINQ doesn't recognize & support it. You need another approach on that.

Comment: This is wrong. `ParseIndices` is captured in a lambda and can perfectly be used in a LINQ query.